# Exclude integer values from list that have difference less than 80

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains many values like

```
mylist = [4361, 4868,4878, 5395, 5940, 6539, 6544, 7164 ]
```

In case I have values that have difference less than 80,  like `4868,4878` I want to exclude the second one and keep only `4868` and **get the indexes** of the those that are deleted.

The new resulted list will be

```
my_list = [4361, 4868, 5395, 5940, 6539, 7164]
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: My list contains values in ascending order only.

Comment: How about `[10, 50, 80, 200]`? Does that become `[10, 200]`? Similarly, what happens with `[10, 50, 120, 200]`?

Comment: @PM2Ring It will be `[10, 200]` yes. For the second one it will be `[10, 120]`.

Comment: `[mylist[j]  for j in range(len(mylist)) if j==0 or mylist[j]-mylist[j-1]>80]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the list is sorted, just compare the current value to the last value in the result list, if any, and append it if the difference is sufficiently large.

```
mylist = [4361, 4868,4878, 5395, 5940, 6539, 6544, 7164 ]
n = 80
result, deleted = [], []
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    if result == [] or x - result[-1] > n:
        result.append(x)
    else:
        deleted.append(i)
print(result)  # [4361, 4868, 5395, 5940, 6539, 7164]
print(deleted) # [2, 6]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
mylist = [4361, 4868, 4878, 5395, 5940, 6539, 7164]

new = [x for x, y in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]) if y - x >= 80]
if mylist[-1] - new[-2] >= 80:
    new.append(mylist[-1])
```

Comment: Yes, but in the result list, the difference would be greater than 80 if you take `[50, 150, 250, ...]`. That's a bit unclear in the question, but clarified in comments.

Comment: Also, you could do this in one line by padding with `None` (or using `itertools.zip_longest`): `[x for x, y in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]+[None]) if y is None or y - x >= 80]`